# Error on mt-table+native table in angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-material2

I'm trying to do a mat-table from material2  and a native table following this example 
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/table/native-table/native-table.html
But i get the next message.

**Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'. ("
  

  ][dataSource]="dataSource" matSort [class.isMobile]="isMobile">**

Anyone has idea of what is going on?

Comment: Please post what you have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was only added recently and merged end of mars in the dev master branch

https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/10594

So unless you are using dev master for angular material, you have to wait a bit for this feature to be available in a proper release